# How to find the angle of an ellipse from the origin?

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

I have the following problem where I'm trying to place the center of the smaller black ellipse where the red diagonal line crosses the blue ellipse (where the arrow is pointing), but I've only been able to put it in $x = b\cos(\theta)$ where $b$ is the semi minor axis. I know how to calculare $y$, I just need to come up with the right $x$ for when the red diagonal line crosses the blue ellipse. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the angle $\theta$ lets define the equation of a line through the origin at an angle $\theta$ from the x-axis:

$$
y = \tan(\theta) \, x
$$

Let's also define your ellipse (centered at the origin) by the equation, for some constants $a$ and $b$:

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

Now we have two equations of two unknowns, which we can solve. Substituting in the first equation to the second:

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2(\theta) \, x^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

Factor out the $x^2$:

$$
x^2 \left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{\tan^2(\theta)}{b^2}\right) = 1
$$

Solve for $x$

$$
x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{\tan^2(\theta)}{b^2}\right)}}
$$

Simplify a bit (by multiplying by $\frac{ab}{ab}$):

$$
x = \pm \frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2 + a^2\tan^2(\theta)}}
$$

In reality, you only care about the positive $x$, so you can drop the $\pm$.

To get $y$ you can just substitute the value you get for $x$ back into the equation for ellipse, solved for $y$:

$$
y = \pm \frac{b\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{a}
$$

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you very much. I'm just confused why it worked. I understood that we substitute y by its definition, but why does that work? What's the intuition?

Comment: Say we have two functions, $f$ and $g$, and define equations $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$. Both relate $y$ to $x$, but not necessarily the same values. $y_1 = f(5) = 17 \neq 29 = g(5) = y_2$, as an arbitrary example. However, by substituting the free variable, $y$, with the other equation, we constrain both equations to the subset of the domain that satisfies both. In your case, the subset is the intersection of the ellipse and line.

Comment: One more question: how did you get the final equation solved for x? I didnt understand how multiplying the equation by ab/ab would result in the final equation.